# Delete last row using Ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using Ormlite for database operations on my Android App.

In one of the methods, I need to delete the last row in a table. However I m not able to find out how. I'm successfully deleting rows when giving an argument, but in this specific case I don't have arguments.

Here's my attempt:

```
  LottoDatabaseHelper helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseHelper.class);
    //You get helper
    Dao dao = helper.getDao(MyTable.class);

    //get your Dao
    DeleteBuilder<MyTable, Integer> deleteBuilder = dao.deleteBuilder();

    //How can I specify last row here?

    deleteBuilder.delete();
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Ormlite .. here is a simple solution which can use with any database ... As you said you can delete a row by passing argument...

try this..

```
1. Find the last id using the query..
eg. SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
// will return the last row id

2. then pass the id as a parameter to delete ...
```

Comment: yes I know I can do this, but I'd rather find how it can be done without this extra step